# Why can't I call object methods from AppDelegate? No known class method for selector

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `DataHandler` class which acts like a singleton, and it has `sharedHandler` object method. I use it throughout the whole project, but for some reason, I can't use it in AppDelegate.

**DataHandler.h**

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    @interface DataHandler : NSObject

    + (id)sharedHandler;
    - (void)logout;
    @end
```

**DataHandler.m**

```
#import "DataHandler.h"

/**
 * Singleton static method
 * @return singleton instance
 */
+ (id)sharedHandler {
    static DataHandler *sharedHandler = nil;
    @synchronized (self) {
        if (sharedHandler == nil)
            sharedHandler = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedHandler;
}

-(void) logout {
    // ...
}


@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "DataHandler.h"

@implementation AppDelegate {

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[DataHandler sharedHandler] logout];
}

@end
```

I keep getting:

```
Error: no known class method for selector 'sharedHandler`
Error: no known instance method for selector 'logout'
```

What is the cause of this behavior?

Comment: You don't have two files named `DataHandler.h`, do you?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue.  Make sure the correct target membership is set on `DataHandler.m`.  Also, use dispatch_once instead when creating a singleton: http://blog.bjhomer.com/2011/09/synchronized-vs-dispatchonce.html

Comment: Target is set fine, like I said, I use this class everywhere in the project, and just removing it from AppDelegate makes the project build and work fine. @KevinBallard you are right... After I have updated git two template files DataHandler .h & .m appeared in the root directory of my project, which were not added to the project navigator, so I didn't see them. I've used Finder to search for it and it appeared... I would have not guessed it :/ Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two files named `DataHandler.h` and the import in `AppDelegate.m` is picking up the wrong file. Note that it may be picking up a file that's not actually in your project, as long as it's in the folder on disk.

Comment: Thank you Kevin, that's exactly what happened. I didn't see the file in AppCode and since it worked in other classes stored in subdirectories of the project, I didn't anticipate the cause.